# Capture failures when using Ruby open3 standard library

Tags: ruby

I'm running an external command using the [`Open3.popen2e`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2e) function. The external command fails spectacularly halfway through. Unfortunately this also kills my ruby process that is using `popen2e`. What is the reason, and how can I avoid?

```
begin
  Open3.popen2e("node mynode.js") do |i, oe|
    oe.each do |ln|
      puts ln.chomp
    end
  end
rescue => exception
  puts exception.message
end
```

Using ruby 2.5.1 on Ubuntu

Comment: all snarky comments about using Ruby to run a node.js program welcome, and heartily agreed with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the reason, but a non-`StandardError` may be raised. So, what about changing your rescue to:

```
rescue Exception => exception
```

That may give you more clues as to what is happening.

Comment: A non-standard error is being raised, and it also contains info about what failed within the external command. If i understand correctly, the rescue didn't capture this error, and sounds like I need to read up on error handling in ruby. Thank you.